# Is there an impact on performance when writing several return statements in a function?

Tags: performance, optimization, return

I was wondering if the use of several *return* statements inside a function had an impact on performance, in comparison with the using of only one *return* statement, at the end of the function.

In interpreted languages, I assume there is not any impact (but correct me if I am wrong), but I wonder for compiled languages.